# Refusal of Italian Tourist visa for 17 days

Tags: schengen, italy, visa-refusals

I am an Indian working in Central Government and have applied for an Italian tourist visa for 17 days (to visit Rome-florence-paris-Vience-Rome-India). But my visa application got rejected with the reason
"information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and condition of intended stay is not reliable".

I have already submitted my original tickets to and from Italy and online hotel bookings, my salary slip, form 16 of the last 3 years, bank statement showing a good amount, nOC form employer and all the other relevant documents. May I know what the reason of refusal is and how I can get it corrected?